# PostgreSQL : Update column A from table A when update on table B if ST_Within(A,B)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to create a function that update table A (point) when table B (polygon) is modified. The reference to B must be changed in A. I can't get it to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maj_A()
    RETURNS trigger AS $foo$    
BEGIN
    UPDATE public."A" AS A
    SET A.a = B.a, 
        A.b = B.b
    FROM public.B AS B
    WHERE ST_WITHIN(A.geom, B.geom) AND NEW.geom <> OLD.geom;
    RETURN NEW;
END;

$foo$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am using postgre 10 and postgis 2.4

Comment: I assume you're binding this function to a CREATE TRIGGER statement

Comment: Yes, but I am stuck on the function.

Comment: You should flag this and have it migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: Please @Boodoo, delete this question from SO and add a new one at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do, but `ST_Within(point, polygon)` sounds really weird, and `ST_Within(a.polygon,b.point)` on an update like that also sounds really weird: how do you know one point isn't in two polygons?

Comment: A polygon boundary will be changed. There's a reference to the polygons in the points. It must be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The following code answers my need.

https://gist.github.com/neogis-de/a1d08c38d8b9c5d316c7

It updates a points layer based on the modification of an overlapping polygons. It only attributes a polygon reference to underlying points without changing anything to a point that was in it and isn't anymore.